# EF Core is it possible to disable update history in temporal tables, only deleted

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Is it possible to keep only the records of deleted records?

I added the temporal tables feature with EF Core and I would like to keep only the deleted records in the temporary table, which by default is storing what has been changed and what has been deleted is possible

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<UserModel>().ToTable("Users", x =>
{
    x.IsTemporal();
});
```

I expected to save only records of deleted records

Comment: Temporal tables are part of Transact SQL not EF. While I could be an error, i simply don't understand how they could provide their functionality without enabling you to query over the history of a table, including joining on foreign keys based on the previous history of that table. This requires tracking of deleted as well as updated and inserted records. However, you can certainly specify a query, and expose it via ef, which filters as you desire.

Comment: No, you can't do that. Temporal tables store everything. But you can do that with simple [Soft Delete](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/06/14/how-to-implement-a-soft-delete-strategy-with-entity-framework-core/) without temporal tables.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Do you think it is possible to implement this with some store procedure? or something like this?

Comment: See also [SqlServerDbSetExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbsetextensions.temporalall?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlserverdbsetextensions-temporalall-1(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbset((-0)))]) provided by EF Core